# What's the song playing in episode 15 when Suguha is practicing Kendo?

Tags: music, sword-art-online

What is the name of the track playing in episode 15 during the part where Suguha is practicing kendo and Kirito interrupts her from behind?

Comment: Is this Love  - it's title

Answer (score 2):

["Is This Love? -Piano Only"](https://youtu.be/7FRgAJ9aOUo) as provided in the comments.